# question on p-adic numbers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Consider the cyclotomic extension $k=\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$ of the p-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and let $ \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$ be the ring of integer of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$. For the uniformizer $ \pi=\sqrt[p-1]{-p}$, the set $ \ \pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$ is a maximal ideal of the ring of integer $ \ \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$.

Then show that $$S=\{x \in \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]: x =\pi^2 x', x' \equiv -\frac{s^2}{2} \mod \pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]), s \in (\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^{*} \} \subset (\pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^2.$$

**My approach:**

We know that $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^*$ can be expressed as $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^{*} \cong \mu_{p-1} \times (1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)$, where $\mu_{p-1}$ is the cyclic group of $(p-1)^{th}$ root of unity in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^{*}=\mathbb{Z}_p-p \mathbb{Z}_p$.

In the same way $ (\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^{*}=(\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])-(p\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])$.

Let $x \in S$, then $x=\pi^2 x', \ x' \equiv -\frac{s^2}{2} (\mod \pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]), \ s \in (\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^{*}$.

But $x=\pi^2 x' \in (\pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^2$ because $x'=-\frac{s^2}{2} \in (\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^{*}$.

So $x  \in S \Rightarrow x \in ( \pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^2$, which implies $S \subset (\pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^2$.

Can someone check my calculation ?

Does the reverse relation $(\pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^2 \subset S$ hold ?

Comment: If you can't prove $(-p)^{1/(p-1)} $ is in the field then don't use it... Its valuation is $1/(p-1)$ so if it is in the field it is an uniformizer. My comment stays the same when changing of $\pi$.

Comment: @reuns, because this uniformizer $\pi=\sqrt[p-1]{-p}$ helped me in my research work rather than the another uniformizer $\pi=\zeta_p-1$. That is why I chosen it.  My request to you is  please check (above) my approach and help me to prove the reverse inclusion if possible, I am not sure whether $S=(\pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^2$ holds or not

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $\zeta_p$ is $f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} x^j = \prod_{j=1}^{p-1} (x-\zeta_p^j)$ thus $f(1) = \prod_{l=1}^{p-1} (1-\zeta_p^l)$ so $\varpi=1-\zeta_p$ has valuation $v(\varpi)=v(f(1))/(p-1) = 1/(p-1)$ and is an uniformizer. 

$\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p] / (\pi)^*$ has representatives $\{ \zeta_{p-1}^m \}$

For $p \ne 2$ the binomial series for $(1+x)^{1/2}$ converges for $v(x) > 0$ thus $(\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p])^2=   \{ \varpi^{2l} \zeta_{p-1}^2(1+\varpi x),m \ge 0, x\in \Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p], l \ge 0\} \cup \{0\}$

Comment: @reuns, sir, you showed $ (\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^2=\{ \bar{\omega}^{2l} \zeta_{p-1}^2(1+\bar{\omega}x), m \geq 0, x \in \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p], l \geq 0 \} \cup \{0 \}$, but I asked for $(\pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^2$.

Comment: $= \pi^2 (\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p])^2$

Comment: @reuns, then what do you mean by $=\pi^2 (\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^2$ ?

Comment: Do you understand that $\varpi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p] = \pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$,  $(\varpi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^2 = (\pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^2$ ? Do you understand how I obtained my description of $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]^2$, and that it stays the same when changing of uniformizer ? Do you understand that $\varpi = \pi u$ for some $u \in \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]^\times$ so $u = \zeta_{p-1}^m (1+\pi x)= \zeta_{p-1}^l (1+\varpi y)$ ?

Comment: @yes sir, I understood that part, but can you comment on my own answer above  where I have to $S=(\pi \mathbb{Z}_p [\zeta_p])^2$. Was my approach correct or not, just comment me please.

Comment: No. Do you understand that (for $p$ odd) every element of $1+\pi \Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$ is a square. This is the only approach, there are no other.

Comment: @reuns,  You said. For $p≠2$ the binomial series for $(1+x)^{1/2}$ converges for $v(x)>0$ thus $(Z[ζ_p])^2=\{ϖ^{2l}ζ_{p−1}^2(1+ϖx), \cdots \}∪{0}$. Can you please explain why the convergence of binomial series giving $(Z[ζ_p])^2=\{ϖ^{2l}ζ_{p−1}^2(1+ϖx) \}$ ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $p \neq 2$ (for $p=2$, I am not sure if the definition of $S$ even makes sense).

I claim your sets are equal for $p \equiv 1,3$ mod $8$ (i.e. $p=3, 11, 17, 19, 41, 43, ...$), but otherwise are disjoint.

Let $K$ be any finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$, with ring of integers $A$ and uniformiser $\pi$. Then it is a standard fact (but needs $p \neq 2$) that every element of the principal units $1+\pi A$ is a square. Further, say $A/\pi \simeq \Bbb F_q$ (in your case, $q=p$), and let $\xi$ denote a *primitive* $q-1$-th root of unity in $K$. Then we have

$(\pi A^\ast)^2 = \pi^2 \cdot \langle\xi^2\rangle \cdot (1+\pi A)$

whereas in your case $K= \Bbb Q_p(\zeta_p)$, the set $S$ is

$S = \pi^2 \cdot (-1/2) \cdot\langle\xi^2\rangle \cdot (1+\pi A)$.

These two sets are equal if and only if $-1/2$ is a square in $\Bbb F_p^\times$; and if it's not, they are disjoint. (In particular, your line

> "But $x = \pi^2 x' \in (\pi \Bbb Z_p[\zeta_p])^2$ because $x' = -\frac{s^2}{2} \in (\pi \Bbb Z_p[\zeta])^*$"

is wrong resp. makes no sense (what is $(\pi \Bbb Z_p[\zeta])^*$?); you would need $x' \in (\Bbb Z_p[\zeta])^2$ which, because all principal units are squares and $s^2$ is a square, is equivalent to $-1/2$ being a square.)

Finally, playing around with quadratic reciprocity, one sees that $-1/2$ is a square in $\Bbb F_p^\times$ iff $p \equiv 1$ or $p \equiv 3$ mod $8$: The first case is the one in which both $-1$ and $2$ are squares mod $p$, the second case is the only one in which both $-1$ and $2$ are *non*-squares mod $p$, so their quotient must be a square.

Comment: Now it makes sense, but it's wrong due to the issue I pointed out. When (modulo $\pi$), $s$ runs through $\Bbb F_p^\times$, $s^2$ runs through the squares in $\Bbb F_p^\times$, but $-\frac{s^2}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}s^2$ runs through the squares iff $-1/2$ is a square, but through the non-squares otherwise, and that last dichotomy happens for the respective classes of primes I mentioned.

Comment: No, that case is not OK in general, and that's what I said. Are you sure you understand what is going on?

Comment: If you replace "$-\frac{s^2}{2}$" with "$s^2$", the two sets are equal, and after that change you can let $s$ come from those sets $R_p$ as well. Of course then it's a different set. Where does that $-1/2$ in your $S$ come from anyway? Maybe you cannot just leave it out.

Comment: Well in that case $A=\Bbb Z_p[\zeta_p]$, so ... -- I want to point out though that, with that change, the equality is nearly trivial (or it should be; you should first understand reuns' comments), and I wonder whether you can just make that change in whatever application you are dealing with. May I ask again where the $-s^2/2$ originally comes from?

Comment: Well but $-s^2$ is not much better than $-s^2/2$; then it's wrong for all $p \equiv 3$ mod $4$. To your last comment, sorry but no (and I'm not a professor anyway).

Comment: I am glad to see that a new version (v4) of https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09850 finally takes this into account. Now the problem is that before this revision, the oversight of this issue about $-1/2$ had cancelled out another error in that preprint; now it does not get cancelled and corollary 1.1.1. would actually prove that for $p \equiv 5,7$ the image is NOT what it is. The error is that the calculation before, starting from "By Fermat's little theorem" is wrong, as I also explained in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3854702/96384. To put my finger on it, $b-b^p \notin p\mathbb Z_p[\zeta_p]$.