# I want to show $\log_p(\alpha+a_0 \pi)=-\frac{\beta^2}{2} \pi^2+\pi^3 \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$, for $p \neq 2$.

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Consider the cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$, its ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$ and uniformizer $\pi$.

Also assume that $\log_p(\alpha) \in p \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$ for $\alpha \neq 0$. Here $\log_p$ is $p$-adic logarithm.

> I want to show $\log_p(\alpha+a_0 \pi)=-\frac{\beta^2}{2} \pi^2+\pi^3 \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$, for  $p \neq 2$, $a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$.

proceeding,
\begin{align}
\log_p(\alpha+a_0 \pi) &=\log_p(\alpha)+\log_p(1+a_1 \pi), \ \text{where} \ a_1=\frac{a_0}{\alpha} \in \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p].
\end{align}
If we assume $a_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]-\pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$, then $a_1=\beta+a_2 \pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$ with $\beta \in \{0,1,2, \cdots, p-1\}$ and $a_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$.
Then, \begin{align}
\log_p(\alpha+a_0 \pi) &=\log_p(\alpha)+\log_p(1+(\beta+a_2 \pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta] \pi)) \\
&=\left[(\beta+a_2 \pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta] \pi)-\frac{(\beta+a_2 \pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta] \pi)^2}{2}+\frac{(\beta+a_2 \pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta] \pi)^3}{3}-\cdots \right]+\log_p(\alpha)
\end{align}

From the second term of $RHS$, we get $-\frac{\beta^2}{2} \pi^2$,

but how to manipulate and abolish other terms in order to get the conclusion.

If $\log_p(\alpha+a_0 \pi)=-\frac{\beta^2}{2} \pi^2+\pi^3 \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$, for  $p \neq 2$ doesn't exactly hold , what would be the nearby relation ?

I mean, I need  $\log_p(\alpha+a_0 \pi)=-\frac{\beta^2}{2}\pi^2+(\cdots \? \cdots)$, for  $p \neq 2$.

Any help please.

Comment: Is there some assumption on $a_0$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng, sorry for late, but yes, $a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this boils down to
$$\log_p(1+\beta\pi)\equiv-\frac{\beta^2}2\pi^2\pmod{\pi^3}.$$
Well,
$$\log_p(1+\beta\pi)=\beta\pi-\frac{\beta^2}{2}\pi^2+\cdots+\frac{\beta^p}{p}\pi^p
-\cdots.\tag{*}$$
You want the $\beta\pi$ and $\beta^p\pi^p/p$ terms to "cancel" appropriately.
As you say, $\beta=b+\gamma\pi$ where $b\in\Bbb Z$. Also you can choose the uniformiser
in the extension field to satisfy  $\pi^{p-1}=-p$. In this case
$$\frac{\beta^p}p\pi^p=-(b+\gamma\pi)^p\pi\equiv-b^p\pi
\equiv-b\pi\pmod{\pi^{p+1}}$$
so that $\beta\pi+\beta^p\pi^p/p$ is certainly zero modulo $\pi^3$. I reckon
that the terms in (*) not listed there have $\pi$-valuation at least $3$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice technique

Comment: You show that $\dfrac{\beta^p}{p}\pi^p \equiv -b\pi$ mod $\pi^{p+1}$, but since $\beta = b +\gamma\pi$ this actually implies $\beta \pi + \beta^p \pi^p/p \equiv \gamma \pi^2$ mod $\pi^3$ and hence $\log_p(1+\beta \pi) \equiv (\gamma-\dfrac{\beta^2}{2})\pi^2$ mod $\pi^3$. Try with $1+\beta \pi = \zeta_p$. The OP's claim is false, fortunately, because otherwise $\log_p$ would not have the full ideal $(\pi^2)$ as its image.

Comment: Do you not agree?

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: $\alpha:=1, a_0:= \dfrac{\zeta_p-1}{\pi}$, so that $\alpha + a_0 \pi =\zeta_p$ and hence $$(*) \qquad \log_p(\alpha+a_0\pi)= \log_p(\zeta_p)=0.$$

But following your notation, we have $a_1=a_0$ and obviously $a_0 \in \mathbb Z_p[\zeta_p]^*$ meaning $\beta \not \equiv 0$ mod $(\pi)$, so if we had
$$ \log_p(\alpha+a_0\pi) \stackrel{?}\equiv -\dfrac{\beta^2}{2}\pi^2 \text{ mod } \pi^3$$
this would contradict $(*)$.

The error in the other answer is explained in my comment to it.

Comment: How do you know $v(\pi)=1$ ? If $v(\pi) \neq 1$, in that case $a_0 \notin (\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p])^{*}$.

Comment: I never used a valuation $v$. In any case, you *defined* $\pi$ as a *uniformiser* of $\mathbb Z_p[\zeta_p]$, so $v(\dfrac{\zeta_p-1}{\pi})=0$ regardless of how the valuation is normalised, i.e. my $a_0$ is in $\mathbb Z_p[\zeta_p]^*$.

Comment: Ok, yeh I got it

Comment: Then it's questionable that you accept a wrong answer.

Comment: In  right time i will do that. Let me think about more carefully before doing any step

Comment: Results of thinking?

Comment: Sorry. I am still confused because my question is correct upto verification by several persons while you found it invalid. I am not justifying your claim as correct or wrong rightnow.  I will look at the proper restrictions. It needs some time because I am busy with another study right now

Comment: Any news on this? Maybe those "several persons" overlooked something, probably exactly this counterexample and what I explained in the comment to the other answer=

Comment: Just checking if your confusion has cleared in the meanwhile?

Comment: I think my question lacks some more information. May be I couldn't explained it well also. More importantly, I jumped into other topics from this topic long ago.  Both answers are reasonable to me, apparently. So I wish to remain as it is.

Comment: That makes no sense. My answer gives a counterexample to the claim in the other answer, and my comment to the other answer explains exactly where its argument is wrong. Seeing two things which contradict each other as reasonable is not reasonable.

Comment: this makes sense because of the first sentence of my above comment.

Comment: Well if there is some "more information" which somehow resolves the contradiction between my counterexample and the claim in the question, then it would be kind and right if you added that information to the question.

Comment: I confess my mistake in formulating the question but as I said I jumped to other topic and so it is difficult to recheck my question as well as the both answers.